# Get all files from a OCI image?

Tags: docker, oci-container

Is there a way to get all files from a OCI image?

This does not really work:

```
docker save ghcr.io/foo/ccm-foo-staging | tar -t
3e90c54e7a793363ccff8a23694fab3ab02d1c5595db26b4b00b8eae62b30611/
3e90c54e7a793363ccff8a23694fab3ab02d1c5595db26b4b00b8eae62b30611/VERSION
3e90c54e7a793363ccff8a23694fab3ab02d1c5595db26b4b00b8eae62b30611/json
3e90c54e7a793363ccff8a23694fab3ab02d1c5595db26b4b00b8eae62b30611/layer.tar
be9484c852d7ee8a3ab0516eaaae736ecc096374f515d7c29010ad61691f0c99.json
dc93a81321b4dc98b32dbcbb83d3d6355d5bb6f2711e281a0a8919ea17a0f184/
dc93a81321b4dc98b32dbcbb83d3d6355d5bb6f2711e281a0a8919ea17a0f184/VERSION
dc93a81321b4dc98b32dbcbb83d3d6355d5bb6f2711e281a0a8919ea17a0f184/json
dc93a81321b4dc98b32dbcbb83d3d6355d5bb6f2711e281a0a8919ea17a0f184/layer.tar
manifest.json
repositories
```

I would like to get the files without layers, just like the process would see them.

I can't use `docker export` since the container does not start.

Comment: Could you `docker create` a container, without starting it?